# Why does changing the 'a' value in this graph not alter the overall volume of the enclosed shape?

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections

This is an application question about finding two parabolic shaped containers (stored underground) that stores the same volume of water and exploring the strength & weaknesses of each shape (in terms of how easy they are to clean, drain etc.) and assumptions. I don't understand how by entering these two equations one can alter the 'a' value without changing the overall volume the container can contain. Also, when 'a' is negative, the red horizontal line disappears, why is that?

Note: the value 2331971.104 is the volume required. That equation is obtained using solids of revolution.

Can anyone think of any strength and weaknesses or assumptions?

[graph of 'a' value as 0.005](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnOAY.png)

[graph of 'a' value is 0.2, graph is thinner but overall volume doesn't change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRndv.png)

Comment: Well the red line is defined from a square root...when a is negative the expression becomes imaginary.

Comment: Ah that's true. How come altering the 'a' would cause the y = ax^2 graph to move up and down to compensate for the change?